# GAWK-Writing output to the beginning of a file

Tags: unix, gawk

I have created a script in GAWK, which produces a log file.

I have a number of conditions throughout the script for error handling, and these errors are output to the log file if triggered. I also have a counter which increments when ever an error is encountered. At the end of the script I have the following:

```
if (intCounter) {
    print "the file contains " intCounter " errors, please see below for details" >> LOG_FILE
} else {
    print "no errors, operation successful" >> LOG_FILE
}
```

This is being printed at the end of my log file, in GAWK is there any way of printing something as the first record in a file if that file already contains text?

Thanks,

Shaw

Comment: You need to read the file twice then.  Do look at `FNR==NR` to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
cat file
data
some other data
here vi have out pattern
this should work
```

```
awk 'FNR==NR {if (/pattern/) f=1;next} f {print "This file has pattern";f=0} 1' file file
This file has pattern
data
some other data
here vi have out pattern
this should work
```